# Label.text is not updating

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, segue

The problem is label.text value became nil every time all the time accept in viewload. I do not know what is the issue.

I have this code in swift 3 Xcode 8, I have a label as shown below

Label to be set later

[image]

then I want to assign the label a value when the view loads as initial value

This is once view loads and it is working fine :)

[image]

later on I want to change the label value to the current Date which I would like it to be set when the user moves to another view the comes back , so I made the function open as you say ..

Here is how I call the function

function call from secondViewController

[image]

finally I want to set it to those values

[image]

[last desired values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfr1C.png)

Comment: [3]:  " https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFy5k.png " 
  [4]:  <---->https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfr1C.png-------

Comment: copy your code and paste it instead of image.

Comment: Where do you call `calcPray`?

Comment: I call calcPray in SecondViewController function prepare for seque

Comment: Chatty titles and questions featuring lengthy begging messages just create work for volunteers. Please keep it succinct, and avoid pleading for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your firstviewcontroller ,define a property say :

```
var x : String?
```

Now in your secondview controller do this :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            let firstviewcontroller = segue.destination as! FirstViewController

            firstviewcontroller.x = "sample value"
          // sample value will be displayed on the firstview controller when u move from secondviewcontroller to firstviewcontroller on the label
}
```

Now in firstviewcontroller set the label in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
dateItem?.text = x
```

**Note:** No need to create another instance of FirstViewController in `prepare` function because the inbuilt function of UIViewController `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` is responsible for going from one view controller to other , you just have to compare the identifier

Comment: I did your solution.. it looks really right and understandable but boooom another error :) Thread1: SIGABRT , the erroe shown in AppDelegate .. I never used the AppDelegate

Comment: @Abdullah Set the exception breakpoint to get the line of the *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil* crash.

Comment: @vadian could not do that not an expert :( help

Comment: @Abdullah did you rename your outlet or something ?

Comment: @Abdullah You have a lingering connection to a no-longer-existent outlet. Double check this via the main storyboard file.

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal yes I did,  i deleted the old name then I dragged the label again and gave it new name

Comment: @Abdullah you have to delete the old connection in your connection inspector also in the right bar

Comment: yes error gone thanx @SamarthKejriwal but still label wont update :((

Comment: @Abdullah get in touch with this tutorial, i hope it will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fbTHFH3tl4

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in the other answer , I not passing data I'm just calling a function ... thanks for the effort @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: See if you want to call a function then you can directly create an instance of the class and call that method, no need to use the `prepare` method

Comment: i passing other data for other strings and it worked ...Look,  I tried to print the value before I assign it to label.text it is Optional("not working")

Comment: you said you dont want to pass data , you want to calla function

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in prepare for segue. When you have got your reference using segue.destination to the firstViewController, you don't need to do
`s = FirstViewController()`, by this you are creating a new instance and not using the one which will actually get initialised during the segue, use `firstController.calcPray()`

Comment: Even if I am not passing the any value to the firstviewcontroller ??

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you meant by that? Can you explain what are you trying to ask by saying "not passing any values to firstviewcontroller" ?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is I'm just calling the calcPray() when the user leaves the secondviewcontroller so ,  creating new instance will not cause any problem since the label.text will be set to a value generated in the firstviewcontroller ... I hope it is clear now

Comment: No you are wrong. By doing s = firstViewController(), you will get access to s.label and not firstController.label. These are two very different things. In simple words, firstController.label will be initialised and kept in the memory and as soon as the prepareforsegue method finishes  "s" instance of FirstViewController will be also be deleted.

Comment: you never create view controller references on your own in prepareforsegue, otherwise swift developers would not have provided segue.destination method, think about it!

Comment: Thank you... I got your point .. this is may be because I'm kind of new to swift and coding essentials 101 :) /// Appropriated your effort ,, I learned new thing from you Dark Innocence

Comment: Done. btw I'm also new in here :| it's little hard to keep up with answers and voting and stuff :)

Comment: no error no crushing now but ... label wont update :(

Comment: does label displays "---------------" ?/

Comment: Yes it does display "--------" in adition to the value of x "Samlple value" suggested by samarth